# Flutter firebase realtime database how to update multiple children?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm trying to update multiple children in flutter: update all the orders in the jobs. In Android I could do this:

```
public void setJobOrder(final ArrayList<Job> jobs) {
  Map map = new HashMap();
  for (int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
    map.put(jobs.get(i).id + "/order", i + 1);
  }
  jobsRef.updateChildren(map);
}
```

In flutter I came up something like this:

```
Future setJobOrder(List<Job> jobs) async{
  Map map = {};

  for(int i = 0; i<jobs.length; i++){
    map[jobs[i].id] = {'order': i};
  }

  return (await _getJobsRef()).update(map);
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 8693): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

My structure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Future setJobOrder(List<Job> jobs) async{
  Map map = {};
  for(int i = 0; i<jobs.length; i++){
    map[jobs[i].id + '/order'] = i;
  }

  return (await _getJobsRef()).update(map.cast<String, dynamic>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create map where key is **Path** and value 
and then use `update` method to update children

as example if we want to update name for two users , we pass path for every user and value then update to main ref

```
Map<String,dynamic> childrenPathValueMap = {};

childrenPathValueMap["users/${userId1}/name"] = "user value 1";
childrenPathValueMap["users/${userId2}/name"] = "user value 2";

FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().update(childrenPathValueMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Map map = {}` on the variable declaration, try using:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WriteBatch to multiple update,
in my case, i update multiple playlist

```
 WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
  for (var playlist_id in playlist_ids) {
    batch.update(
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(playlist_collection_name)
            .doc(playlist_id),
        {
          "song_ids": FieldValue.arrayUnion([song_id]),
          "total_songs": FieldValue.increment(1),
        });
    status = true;
  }
  // update all the docs
  batch.commit();
```